# How to get object ID onPress and pass that value on to a new screen in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I've build an React Native app which shows a list of different `objects` on the `ListScreen`. I now want to with `onPress` show one `object` values on the `ViewScreen`

I've build my app using React-Redux and React-navigation now I'm not sure if I should store the data of the object in the `store`, but I'm not sure if that's the right way to use the Redux store (because I currently use it for the cart items) or If there is another way to pass on these value's on to the `ViewScreen`.

This is a simplification of my app:

I've made a static `Data.js` file to test app

**Data.JS**

```
`id: 0, 
 name: 'John Doe', 
 age: '15',
 gender: 'male',
`
```

Then I import the data into the `ListScreen`

**List.js**

```
`import { object} from './Data';
 state = {
    object, 
  };
renderRow = (rowData) => { 
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.id.navigation.navigate('ViewScreen')}> 
                <View>
                <Text>
                {rowData.item.name}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (    
        <View>
             <FlatList
             renderItem={this.renderRow}
             keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
         />
        </View>
    )
  }
`
```

**ViewScreen**

```
` state = {
    object, 
  };
renderRow = (rowData) => { 
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.id.navigation.navigate('ViewScreen')}> 
                <View>
                <Text>
                {rowData.item.name}
                                {rowData.item.age}
                                {rowData.item.gender}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (    
        <View>
             <FlatList
             renderItem={this.renderRow}
             keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
         />
        </View>
    )
  }
`
```

How do I pick it up from here? So that the value's get shown in the `ViewScreen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost there just add this second argument to your on press method and it's done.

You will get this data in data prop of next screen.

```
renderRow = (rowData) => { 
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
            this.props.id.navigation.navigate('ViewScreen',{data : rowData})}> 
                <View>
                <Text>
                  {rowData.item.name}
                  {rowData.item.age}
                  {rowData.item.gender}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer only it returns `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.id.navigation')` meaning it can't find the object

Comment: try binding renderRow in constructor and see if it helps.

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: the error you are getting could mean one of two things either your component is not getting navigation props or your function is unable to access (this) keyword.